# Python asyncio wait() with cumulative timeout

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am writing a job scheduler where I schedule M jobs across N co-routines (N < M).  As soon as one job finishes, I add a new job so that it can start immediately and run in parallel with the other jobs.  Additionally, I would like to ensure that no single job takes more than a certain fixed amount of time.  Any jobs that take too long should be cancelled.  I have something pretty close, like this:

```
def update_run_set(waiting, running, max_concurrency):
    number_to_add = min(len(waiting), max_concurrency - len(running))
    for i in range(0, number_to_add):
        next_one = waiting.pop()
        running.add(next_one)

async def _run_test_invocations_asynchronously(jobs:List[MyJob], max_concurrency:int, timeout_seconds:int):
    running = set()     # These tasks are actively being run
    waiting = set()     # These tasks have not yet started

    waiting = {_run_job_coroutine(job) for job in jobs}
    update_run_set(waiting, running, max_concurrency)

    while len(running) > 0:
        done, running = await asyncio.wait(running, timeout=timeout_seconds,
                                           return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        if not done:
            timeout_count = len(running)
            [r.cancel() for r in running]                # Start cancelling the timed out jobs
            done, running = await asyncio.wait(running)  # Wait for cancellation to finish 
            assert(len(done) == timeout_count)
            assert(len(running) == 0)
        else:
            for d in done:
                job_return_code = await d

        if len(waiting) > 0:
            update_run_set(waiting, running, max_concurrency)
            assert(len(running) > 0)
```

The problem here is that say my timeout is 5 seconds, and I'm scheduling 3 jobs across 4 cores.  Job A takes 2 seconds, Job B takes 6 seconds and job C takes 7 seconds.

We have something like this:

```
  t=0     t=1     t=2     t=3     t=4     t=5     t=6     t=7
-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

However, at t=2 the `asyncio.await()` call returns because A completed.  It then loops back up to the top and runs again.  At this point B has already been running for 2 seconds, but since it starts the countdown over, and only has 4 seconds remaining until it completes, B will appear to be successful.  So after 4 seconds we return again, B is successful, then we start the loop over and now C completes.

How do I make it so that B and C both fail?  I somehow need the time to be preserved across calls to `asyncio.wait()`.

One idea that I had is to do my own bookkeeping of how much time each job is allowed to continue running, and pass the *minimum* of these into `asyncio.wait()`.  Then when something times out, I can cancel only those jobs whose time remaining was equal to the value I passed in for `timeout_seconds`.

This requires a lot of manual bookkeeping on my part though, and I can't help but wonder about floating point problems which cause me to decide that it's not time to cancel a job even though it really is).  So I can't help but think that there's something easier.   Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap each job into a coroutine that checks its timeout, e.g. using `asyncio.wait_for`. Limiting the number of parallel invocations could be done in the same coroutine using an `asyncio.Semaphore`. With those two combined, you only need one call to `wait()` or even just `gather()`. For example (untested):

```
# Run the job, limiting concurrency and time. This code could likely
# be part of _run_job_coroutine, omitted from the question.
async def _run_job_with_limits(job, sem, timeout):
    async with sem:
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(_run_job_coroutine(job), timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            # timed out and canceled, decide what you want to return
            pass

async def _run_test_invocations_async(jobs, max_concurrency, timeout):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrency)
    return await asyncio.gather(
        *(_run_job_with_limits(job, sem, timeout) for job in jobs)
    )
```

Comment: Interesting, that simplifies my logic even further due to the `Semaphore` and the gather.  Looking forward to trying this out, thank you!

Comment: Yup, it makes `wait_for()` and the semaphore do the heavy lifting. And `wait_for` just trivially uses `loop.call_later()`, so the timeout bookkeeping and finding the minimum is implemented - in the [guts of the event loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/82e79480d6e61940d7007d9026fbff0b1a11ad9a/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1849).